# Как отключить эффект перехода между Activity?

Tags: android, xml, activity

Добрый день, хочу написать приложение справочник в котором будут переходы между  Activity. Но мне не нравиться сам эффект перехода, он похож на браузерный, когда мы переходим по ссылки, сначала открывается белое окно, а после появляется контент.

Возможно сделать что-то вроде полноценного приложения? Или нужно весь контент размещать в одном Activity?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Есть специальный метод, позволяющий переопределить анимации

```
startActivity(new Intent(....));
overridePendingTransitions(0, 0);
```

0, 0 это параметры exitAnimation и enterAnimation. Можете сами создать анимацию, и передать ее Id в данный метод. 0 значит, что анимации в данном случае не будет.

Comment: Спасибо, попробовал ваш пример. А вы не в курсе, возможно сделать переход без мерцания, скажем как в играх?. Там незаметно происходят переходы, если они конечно там есть.

Comment: Насчет игр не знаю. "сначала открывается белое окно, а после появляется контент" - от этого никуда не деться, т.к нужно время на отрисовку контента. Вы можете сделать два фрагмента в одном активити, и менять их по мере необходимости, тогда активити не будет пересоздаваться, и смена контента станет более быстрой

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, прочту как это реализовать.